# What are the options for installing scripts with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install one python2 and one python3 version of a single script when users install my package through pip. Ideally, these would simply be executable text files with a shebang line indicating #!/usr/bin/env python2 -E or the equivalent for the users system. Is there any way for me to do this?

Pip insists on changing the shebang line for its own purposes and I can't seem to convince it to do otherwise. Right now I'm using entry_points, but I need to move away from that because entry_points can add up to .3 seconds of overhead per call (10x the program runtime). Also, entry_points doesn't let me specify the -E flag, opening up the program to a bug when the PYTHONPATH is malformed.

Comment: This is rather a unusual issue. If performance matters, you usually avoid calling a script over and over again. I don't think there is a nice way in `pip` to solve this specific issue.

Comment: @cel yes, it's not a typical use case. One option would be to just run shell commands from the setup.py to get the text file in the right place. I'd be happy to learn about a way to do this properly. Maybe the pip source has some clues.